# how to customize React native Navigation cardoverlay styles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i would like to implement this black background on the react native navigation stack navigator. I know that passing

a couple properties like these:

```
options={{
    gestureEnabled: true,
    cardOverlayEnabled: true,
    ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS,
    cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forModalPresentationIOS,
    mode: 'modal',
}
```

how can this be implemented?
the cardOverlayEnabled provides grey-ish tone.
i tried to add a View flex 1 with black background, but when i do so, i lost the screen in the back

[image]

Comment: What part of the cards do you want to be black? The card itself?

Comment: no, i want the background. I will edit my question with a sample image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the answer has nothing to do with overlay.
Actually, all the new pages will place on top of each other if you set various pages to open like a swipe up modal like that, and the page that you have not set to up like this but instead place like a full page, this full page will be placed in the very bottom. With this, if you set a black view wrapping your routes, will give a black background effect as desired.